# How to make the pgadmin4 interface become a browser tab?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Previously (maybe around 1 year ago) pgAdmin was just an browser tab, now it's an individual window in windows. How to make the interface become a browser tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to deploy pgAdmin in server mode, as described here: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/server_deployment.html

Comment: This is very hard for me. is there any simple way? I don't want new window. I just want a browser tab.

Comment: A simpler way is to use Docker: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-container/. Then you have pgAdmin in server mode without having to configure a server.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Antoine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7413742/antoine)'s comment in the other answer, simply run:

```
docker run --name webui-pgadmin4 -p 5050:80 -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=pgadmin4@pgadmin.org' -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin' -d dpage/pgadmin4
```

Then access at http://localhost:5050.

It'll be a clean installation, so won't have the configuration from your desktop pgAdmin.  But you can use Tools → Import/Export Servers to copy over the configuration (except passwords.)

This is very useful when you're collaborating with teammates and already sharing a web browser window.  It lets you add a pgAdmin browser tab, instead of switching the application that's being shared, or sharing your entire screen.